# Continue through loop following NoElementException

Tags: python, selenium

I am looping through a set of URLs, scraping data from each. Upon opening the URL, I want to scrape the first (5) results; however, some of these URLs contain less than five results, so I'd like to scrape up to five, then continue to the next URL in my list.

The way my script is currently set up uses `try:` `except:` `continue`, which I understand "continues" the loop from the beginning. My intention is to move on to the next URL as soon as a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown (because I know there are no more results on the page).

**This is the output I'm hoping to achieve** - where "spaceref" only has two results, then the script starts over on the next URL, "freddie mac", who has five results, stops, then moves to the next URL:

```
[{'Result 1': ('spaceref', '40', 'http://www.spaceref.com/mars/')}, 
{'Result 2': ('spaceref dot com', '20', 'http://www.spaceref.com/')},
{'Result 3': ('None')},
{'Result 4': ('None')},
{'Result 5': ('None')} ,
{'Result 1': ('freddie mac', '40K', 'http://www.freddiemac.com/')}, 
{'Result 2': ('freddie mac about', '1400', 'http://www.freddiemac.com/about')}, 
{'Result 3': ('freddie mac services', '1250', 'http://www.freddiemac.com/services')}, 
{'Result 4': ('freddie mac team', '1010', 'http://www.freddiemac.com/team')}, 
{'Result 5': ('freddie mac contact', '750', 'http://www.freddiemac.com/contact')}
{'Result 1': ('lorem ipsum', 'n', 'http://www.example.com')}
{'ETC...'}]
```

**Here's my current script:** (I know there are far more efficient ways to write this. I hate this, too, but finding individual elements by XPath is necessary in this case)

Much thanks for any advice!

```
group_url = [
'https://www.example1.com',
'https://www.example2.com',
'https://www.example3.com'
]

data = []

for group in group_url:
    driver.get(group)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2])))
    try:
        kw1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div')
        vol1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]')
        url1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/main/')
        data.append({
            "Result 1": (kw1.text, vol1.text, url1.text)
            })
    except NoSuchElementException:
        data.append({"Result 1": None})
        continue
    try:
        kw2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div')
        vol2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]')
        url2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/')
        data.append({
            "Result 2": (kw2.text, vol2.text, url2.text)
            })
    except NoSuchElementException:
        data.append({"Result 2": None})
        continue
    try:
        kw3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div')
        vol3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]')
        url3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/main/')
        data.append({
            "Result 3": (kw3.text, vol3.text, url3.text)
            })
    except NoSuchElementException:
        data.append({"Result 3": None})
        continue
    try:
        kw4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div')
        vol4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]')
        url4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]/main/')
        data.append({
            "Result 4": (kw4.text, vol4.text, url4.text)
            })
    except NoSuchElementException:
        data.append({"Result 4": None})
        continue
    try:
        kw5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div')
        vol5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[5]')
        url5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[5]/main/')
        data.append({
            "Result 5": (kw5.text, vol5.text, url5.text)
            })
    except NoSuchElementException:
        data.append({"Result 5": None})
        continue
driver.close()
print(data)
```

**This is my actual output.** Each URL does not seem to be properly running through the loop. For example, I know spaceref has (2) results, so I know it's not giving me the second result. I also know freddie mac has (5) results, which is also not being output. And for the remaining URLs in my list, the output returns only "'Result 1': None":

```
[{'Result 1': ('spaceref', '40', 'http://www.spaceref.com/mars/')}, 
{'Result 2': None}, 
{'Result 1': None},
{'Result 1': None}, 
{'Result 1': None}, 
{'Result 1': None}, 
{'Result 1': None}]
```

Comment: You have described what is the desired behavior, but what is the problem, what is the wrong behavior you currently have with your code?

Comment: Thanks, @Prophet. Please see edits.